# Does it matter that the TTL is higher than I've been told?

Tags: dns, email, shared-hosting, mx

Ok, so the title isn't very descriptive, I know. Basically, I'm trying to configure Outlook.com to use my custom domain! I've followed the steps and made the account etc. and now I have the DNS settings to configure from Windows Live. I added  the MX Entries and everything last night but Windows Live is still saying I need to prove my ownership of the domain.

The only thing I can think of that I had to use a differrent TTL to the one provided because my web hoster will only allow  a minimum of four hours, whereas Windows Live told me to configure the TTL as one hour. Would that stop anything?

By the way, my web hoster is JustHost (Shared Hosting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't *matter* per se, you'll just have to wait longer. Even if you add MX entries, isn't there some sort of verification code you'd need to add to confirm your domain? I know for Google Apps, you can either add a `TXT` record with a short code, or upload a `HTML` file with a code inside.

I'd recommend waiting another day at the latest, and if it still fails, call your web host. If they can't help you, then look into the "verification" of the domain, not just adding `MX` records.

Comment: Oh ok thank you. I figured that must be the case even though on everything I've read it says it only took about two hours, but then again they probably aren't using shared hosting. As for the verification, it does say everything else is optional but I've added all the DNS records Windows Live provided (including the Prove Domain Ownership one)!